# There exists a unique isomorphism between wosets

Tags: set-theory

I need some help with the conclusion of an exercise.
I have to prove that if $(A,R), (B,S)$ are well orderings and $f,g: (A,R) \rightarrow (B,S)$ are order-isomorphisms, then $f=g$.

Suppose that $f\neq g$. Then let $X$ be the set of elements $a\in A$ such that $f(a)\neq g(a)$. $X$ is not empty, so it has minimal element, $\overline a$. We have that $f(\overline a)\neq g(\overline a)$, thus in $B$ we have only two possibilities:

$1)$ $f(\overline a)>g(\overline a)$

$2)$ $f(\overline a)< g(\overline a)$.

I would like to see that these two cases are not possible, but I cannot find contradiction.

Comment: Hint: remember that $f$ and $g$ are order-*isomorphisms*.  This means that they are not only order-preserving, but bijective as well.

Comment: @Paul: That should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Are you saying it's too much of a hint, or that I should have posted it as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @Paul: The latter. I think that as a hint, it's spot-on.

Answer (score 0):

In case 1), think about what should be  $f^{-1}(g(\bar a))$